# how to install gearman on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gearman

I'm trying to install Gearman on Ubuntu 16.04. the gearman documentation said:

> If you are running Debian/sid, run apt-get install gearman-job-server. This package may be slightly out of date due to the time it takes to propagate to the repositories.

I tried to run the following command to install Gearman, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
sudo apt-get install gearman-job-server
```

If I use the following command, it won't display any output.

```
gearmand -d
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

1. run `gearmand` as user permitted to write into default logging file `/var/log/gearmand.log`
2. run `gearmand -d --log-file YOUR-LOGGING-FILE`

Comment: i ran `sudo gearmand -d` . the `/var/log/gearmand.log` output:
`ERROR 2017-09-13 08:02:11.000000 [  main ] Timeout occured when calling bind() for 0.0.0.0:4730 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:616
  ERROR 2017-09-13 08:02:14.000000 [  main ] Timeout occured when calling bind() for 0.0.0.0:4730 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:616`

Comment: I guess an other instance of `gearnand` is already listening at port 4730.  Either kill the other instance or let new once listening at an other port number.

Comment: i ran `sudo netstat -peanut` on terminal. i saw the gearmand has been run:
http://i64.tinypic.com/v42zuq.png.